# Custom Node type CSS, best place to put it in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

I'm building a Drupal 7 type that has two distinct types of page, public ones and ones only shown to authenticated users, with entirely different templates. The choice of which template to use is done in the theme preprocess function.

Each of the two main templates has its own CSS, which needs to be placed in the header in the right place relative to the theme and base CSS. What is the best place to include these CSS files?

I can't add these sheets to the theme .info file, since those are applied to all templates. At the moment I am adding them in the theme preprocess function, but it seems like needless complexity, since the stylesheets are essentially static (all pages with the same template have the same 3 sheets). On the other hand hard-coding them in the template file (e.g. after the normal print $styles) seems like it is "not the drupal way" (tm), and also won't take advantage of CSS compression and caching.

So what *is* the right way?

Answer (score 0):

you have no best place to insert your css file. You can just use drupal_add_css() anywhere you want. The css will be anyway write in the header.